# Modifying Footer links

Tags: magento2, footer-links

In magento 2.2.2 I've created a Block called "**Footer Links**" and I've called the block from a my new widget called "**footer links**".

In the front end, the new links are appearing in a wrong place!!
How can I replace my new block with my themes footer_liks?
please, look at the picture attached[image]

Beside, in my file structure I can see this file:

> app/design/frontend/swissup/argento-essence/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_cms_content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_cms_content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-toolbar-top">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_social">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_social_icons</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_cms_content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_cms_content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer-toolbar-top"/>
    </body>
</page>
```